# What happens if not using 'Bearer ' before JWT token

Tags: node.js, jwt

Many apps I have seen are sending the token by prepending "Bearer" to the JWT token in Node apps. Is it necessary to add "Bearer"? What will happen if I don't use "Bearer"?

```
 "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOjQsImlhdCI6MTU2NzU5MzI0OH0.007Vst4Ht4oEZw1ia64"
```

If I use direct token in headers with Authorization key, what will happen?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re

Comment: It's just a standard. If you don't add `Bearer` before the token then you must make sure that your server also understands the format. Note that since it's a standard, most standard tools like `Postman` and libraries like `jsonwebtoken` and `passport-jwt` either automatically insert the `Bearer` word for bearer tokens or expect the first word to be the token type (Bearer, Digest, Basic etc)

Comment: To answer your question, it depends on the implementation of HTTP headers parser in your app (you probably use a module for this). As stated in the answer linked by AZ_, the "Bearer" keyword specifies the authentication method (or the "protocol" for purists). If you omit it there's a chance it won't be recognized as OAuth and you'll get the 403.8 access denied error (which also depends on the way you handle errors)

Comment: Both comments above would suffice as answers IMO.

Comment: but in postman i enter the key:value pair  as Autherization(key) in headers section  and token(value) without Bearer,it's got worked for me!!

Comment: What worked? Are you talking about calling a specific API or your own API?

Comment: yes talking about calling a specific api